# C# Getting an object reference error when getting a guid from a cookie then need to convert to string

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract a GUID I store as an unique identifier but I keep getting a the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Here’s the code.

```
    protected void btnGetGuid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Guid testGuid = new System.Guid(Server.UrlDecode(Page.Request.Cookies["userid"].Value));

    lblGuidReturn.Text = testGuid.ToString();
}
```

Realizing I’m somewhat new to C#, I’ve written enough Java to understand what is supposed to be going on, but this one's got me buggared.

Once I get the GUID, I need to store it as a string but I think once I get past this issue, that part will work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try stepping thru with the debugger.

Comment: I think the cookie is null, therefore trying to access the value property throws the exception.

Comment: Do it step by step: `var userId = Page.Request.Cookies["userid"]; var userIdValue = ....` you get the idea. Now you see exact there the error is thrown and propebly you can explain it!

Answer (score 0):

Since Guid is a value type, you cannot get object reference error from converting guid instance to string. There are several places which can throw exception you mentioned:

Server.UrlDecode(Page.Request.Cookies["userid"].Value)

Server could be null, since UrlDecode is not static method. (although this is unlikely)

Page could be null.
Request could be null;
Cookies collection could be null.

Most probably cookies collection did not contain "userid" value, and returned null.
UrlDecode could not throw ObjectReference error, since it checks for input parameters.